# How to read files from project folders?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When the first time my app starts on a windows phone, I want to get some files(xml/images) from project folders and write them to the isolated storage .

How do I detect that my app is running for the first time?

How do I access file in project folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean project folders as in the folders in your visual studio project, I usually right click on the files and set the build action to 'Embedded Resource'. At runtime, you can read the data from the embedded resource like so:

```
// The resource name will correspond to the namespace and path in the file system.
// Have a look at the resources collection in the debugger to figure out the name.
string resourcePath = "assembly namespace" + "path inside project";
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string[] resources = assembly .GetManifestResourceNames();
List<string> files = new List<string>();

if (resource.StartsWith(resourcePath))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource), Encoding.Default);
    files.Add(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

To read the images you would need something like this to read the stream:

```
    public static byte[] ReadAllBytes(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;

            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to update/delete/Add a file to a project folder?

Comment: @Ishti no, it's not possible to add, edit or delete files which are distributed in the XAP or embedded inside an assembly (as in this case). You can perform these operations with files in IsolatedStorage though. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541(v=vs.92).aspx) Unless you have a very good reason not to, you will be better off using `Resources` rather than `Embedded Resources`, as Vivek suggested.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way to read files from your visual studio project. The following shows how to read a txt file but can be used for other file as well. Here the file is in the same directory as the .xaml.cs file.

```
var res = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("test.txt", UriKind.Relative));
var txt = new StreamReader(res.Stream).ReadToEnd();
```

make sure your file is marked as Content.