# App crashes when reading from text file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, text-files, streamreader

I am trying to populate a `List<Image>` by reading the name of the each line from within a text file. The text file looks like this:

```
image0
image1
image2
image
...
```

The following code makes my program crash completely and makes Visual Studio freeze.

```
int counter = 0;
string line = string.Empty;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("ItemFile.txt");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     imageCollection.Add(new Image());
     imageCollection[counter].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/" + line + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: I think in WP7, u need to use IsolatedStorage mechanism to read/write files.

Comment: Is there an exception thrown? Mind that loading a big list of big images is expected to be slow.

Comment: If your file is in isolated storage, you should read them from IsolatedStorage. [That guide might help you](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use standard read/write mechanisms on WP7. You have to use IsolatedStorage classes to do that:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("ItemFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{    //Visualize the text data in a TextBlock text
    while ((line = reader .ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         imageCollection.Add(new Image());
         imageCollection[counter].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/" + line + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

If you want read text from file which is added to the device as a part of project during the installation check out this question: [How to read files from project folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531968/how-to-read-files-from-project-folders)

Comment: I get a Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream when I use the above code.