# where is my static content in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstoragefile

I have Windows Phone 8 app in which I want to include my own 10 MP3s. I included them in /Assets, but a call like

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    songs = store.GetFileNames("*.mp3").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Found  {0} files ", songs.Count());
}
```

keeps returning that the # of MP3s in my store is 0.

I tried putting the MP3s in Content, Assets, Resources and set Copy Always option, but to no avail.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read files from project folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531968/how-to-read-files-from-project-folders)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but I couldn't get that working.. here is the sample code I used:                                                          string resourcePath = @"/PhoneApp1;component/Resources/";
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            List<string> files = new List<string>();

            foreach (string resource in resourcePath)
            {
                if (resource.EndsWith("mp3"))
                {
                    //
                }
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set your files as "Embedded Resource", you can get a list of files at runtime.

Here is how you can do this:

1. Set the Build Action of your files as "Embedded Resource".
2. Use Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() to enumerate the resources names

   ```
   string[] GetResourcesNames()
   {
       return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
   }
   ```

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that files are embedded in the DLL, so if you hava a high volume of files, the app load time might take a while :-(

Comment: that worked thanks. So, if my app is ever going to blow up to 100 or 200 files, what will be the ideal way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

The files is not copied to isolated store for your app, but you can get them by the uri:

```
var mymp3file = new Uri("Assets/HomersDoh.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: I need to load a bunch of mp3s. My mp3 list could go from 10 to 50. So, I don't want to load each by file name. I need a load : "Assets/*.mp3" type of solution